# Can't remove zfs log device from pool

Tags: freebsd, zfs, zpool

I run a `FreeBSD 9.0` server with `ZFS pool version 28` and `ZFS version 5`.
I had two pools with a log on ssd's two partitions. These pools was created on FreeBSD 8.2 with ZFS pool version 15, and ZFS version 4. 
After I upgraded to the new zfs version, I tried to remove the SSD log device from both pools both command was successful (no error message). One of the pools was the log removed, but the other still there, I down the server removed the ssd physically, and hoped it will be forgot by the zpool.
The zpool became degraded as ssd was missing. I tied to remove again. No error message, but the log device entry still there. After it, to became the pool online again, I created a file on the root UFS partition and replaced the missing to device to this file. It was successful, the pool again online. However I can't remove the log device from the pool.

Where can I have to look for error messages? (in `dmesg` there is nothing about it, also the `zfs remove` doesn't have any error message, it's seem like it was successful.

Comment: How was the log device added? Or was it attached? Was one of the two log devices mirrored? If there was a difference between the pools and how the log device was included, this could lead to the way you have to remove/detach it again.